# Swift init empty array with the same type as another array

Tags: swift

I'm a very beginner at Swift, so this question might be silly.

I want to have a function, where an empty array is created with the same type as an incoming parameter.

 I tried something like below, but none of it works.

```
private func doSomething<T>(source: [T]) {
    var result = [source]
    var result = [source]()
    var result = [type(of:source)]()
    var result: type(of:source) = Array()
}
```

I see an option to do like this:

```
private func shuffle<T>(source: [T]) {
    var result = source
    result = []
}
```

But is there a better way to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

simply:

```
var result = [T]()
```

or

```
var result: [T] = []
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
private func shuffle<T>(source: [T]) {
    var result: [T] = []
    //do something with your result (being an empty array at this point)
}
```